# Is there a way to specify minimum minibuffer/echo area size in emacs?

Tags: emacs, user-interface

I am running Emacs 24, and due to a separate issue, my input method (uim-el) displays input candidates in the minibuffer regardless of how I set its options. That would not be such a problem if the minibuffer did not resize from height 2 (when displaying candidates) to height 1 (when not), repeatedly, as I scroll through candidates--it's really jarring.

I looked through the documentation online and searched the configuration pages, but I couldn't find a setting for this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `input-method-use-echo-area` to `nil` and `echo-keystrokes` to `0`.

If that doesn't help, try setting `resize-mini-windows` to `nil`.

(You can also try setting `max-mini-window-height` to `1`, but that will likely truncate your echoed input-method candidates.)

Comment: I don't seem to have any of the first three variables available to modify.

Comment: You must have at least the first two, unless your Emacs version is older than Emacs 20 (and even then I'm pretty sure you have at least the second one). If you have Emacs 22 or later then you must have all of them. Try `C-h v` for each. Some are not use options -- you can set them using `setq`.

Comment: Whoops. I found the first two, but not `resize-mini-windows`. Neither one seems to help.

Comment: Wrt `resize-mini-windows`: Is your `M-x emacs-version` less than Emacs 22?  If not then that variable should exist (it is in Emacs 22.1, the first 22 release).  And it is the variable most likely to solve your problem, I believe.  Sorry that the others don't help.

Comment: Strange, reinstalling emacs24 on a fresh system, even with a restored home directory fixed the problem, and made that variable available.